# Scrollbar moves back after WM_VSCROLL

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I have a window with its own H and V scrolling. I'm handling the event like this:

```
case WM_VSCROLL:

        SetScrollPos(hWnd, SB_VERT, (int)HIWORD(wParam), TRUE);

        break;
```

all I want is for the position of the scroll bar to stay once I release my mouse but what it's doing is just going back to the top after. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `wParam` parameter of the `WM_VSCROLL` message is either `SB_TOP`, `SB_BOTTOM`, `SB_PAGEUP`, `SB_PAGEDOWN`, `SB_LINEUP`, `SB_LINEDOWN`, `SB_THUMBPOSITION`, or `SB_THUMBTRACK`, where the names ought to explain themselves.

- `SB_TOP` and `SB_BOTTOM` means that the scrolling window is to go to the top or bottom, respectively. These messages can be sent by right-clicking a vertical scroll bar and selecting "Top" and "Bottom". (Look in Windows Notepad, Win XP+, for instance.)
- `SB_PAGEUP` and `SB_PAGEDOWN` means a page (screen) up or down. These are sent if you click somwhere on the scrollbar beside on the thumb or the up or down arrows, or if you use the scrollbar's right-click menu.
- `SB_LINEUP` and `SB_LINEDOWN` are sent when the user clicks the up and down buttons on the scrollbar, or selects the appropriate right-click menu commands.
- `SB_THUMBTRACK` is sent continuously when the user scrolls by dragging the thumb of the scrollbar.
- `SB_THUMBPOSITION` is sent when the user has released the thumb.

See the MSDN article [WM_VSCROLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787577(VS.85).aspx) for more information.

So, when you receive a WM_VSCROLL message, you first need to do the scrolling itself. If, for instance, you are writing a text editor, then you need to redraw the text, but with a different row at the top of the window. Then you need to update the scrollbar to its new position, preferably by means of SetScrollInfo, but you can also use the old SetScrollPos function.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787531(VS.85).aspx for an example of how to handle the `WM_VSCROLL` message.

Comment: why "preferably by means of SetScrollInfo"?

Comment: @user4215456: Because [`SetScrollPos`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setscrollpos) is deprecated: "Note  The SetScrollPos function is provided for backward compatibility. New applications should use the SetScrollInfo function."

Answer (score 0):

In the case section, the system is processing a WM_VSCROLL message. It will run the default window procedure after your SetScrollPos. In the default window procedure, the system itself will set the scroll bar's thumb position. So, although SetScrollPos takes effects, the system change the thumb position after that anyway. I think you should do your SetScrollPos after calling the default window procedure, i.e., maybe after returning this funciton, and then you can SetScrollPos.